# How to abort an HTTP Request from .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http

When I use fiddler I am able to abort an http request by right clicking to the request and selecting abort session option.  I can confirm this from the server side (I ran ASP.NET Web API) that the client is effectively disconnected. Now I am trying to mimic the same behavior from a `.NET client`.

So far I tried things like, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests` or 
`System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Abort`. However no matter I tried, from fiddler I observe that, despite I am making above calls, the request keeps running and returns a response. In other words, these calls do not cause anything that causes server detecting a disconnect. Is there a way to achieve what I want ?

Comment: Cancelling a *client* request doesn't mean that the *server* will stop processing it. The client will stop waiting for a response and close its own connection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're missing the word "necessarily" there. HTTP servers _can_ detect client disconnects and _can_ act on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the .NET cancel worked but Fiddler continues making the request. Fiddler is not just an observer. It is a man in the middle. It terminates your connection and initiates its own to the server.

You can try this out by making some browser requests and killing the browser process. If Fiddler does not show any kind of message or error then this means that Fiddler simply ignores killed client connections.

You also can test this using Wireshark.

So you don't seem to have a problem. This should work.

Comment: Yes this was my problem. Shutting down fiddler, now everything works properly.